devcontainer: pylance issue
devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "app",
    "dockerComposeFile": "../docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
            "ms-python.python",
        "charliermarsh.ruff"
        ]
        }
    }
}

Whenever I try to create a new file, pylance won't recognize the new file and cause import to fail
For example if I create a new file and try to import it from main.py, i will get the following error
Import "app.sub" could not be resolvedPylance[reportMissingImports]

Now if I reload the the ide window, import works as expected.
Does anyone know how I can resolve this?
